# c# MathNet Gamma distribution sampling not matching

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to implement an event time sampling for different distributions using the MathNet library. I have them working for exponential, normal and weibull but the same process is not working for Gamma anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Testing Example to get mean.

```
    using System;
    using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            double sum = 0.0;
            var dist = new Gamma(0.5,50);
            int runs = 1000000;
            for (int i=0; i<runs; i++)
            {
                sum += dist.Sample();
            }
            Console.WriteLine((sum/runs).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Returns: ~0.01

Using online calculator https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573218 I get 11.37 for the mean. (CD 0.5, shape 0.5 scale 50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to keep in mind:

1. Math.Net is using [shape and rate (or inverse scale)](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/Gamma.htm#.ctor) definition of gamma distribution, while most online calculators are using shape and scale.
2. The lower (or upper) CDF is not equal the expectation value of the distribution: if you do the [integral to calculate the expected value](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_2_6_solved4_2.php), you get `E[X] = shape/rate`, that is quite close to the result you get from your code